# Unable to trigger job in VSTS

Tags: java, build, azure-devops, agent

I am getting the following error when I'm trying to run the job from VSTS -

> No agent found in pool IAMPool which satisfies the specified demands:
>        maven
>        Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.91.0

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: maven already exists in the machine which i have added as agent.

Comment: Maybe Agent.Version is <= 1.91.0

Comment: Agent.Version is greater than 1.91.0

Comment: you say maven exists on that machine but does the agent know that ? check the capabilities of the agent. you might have to add an environmentvariable to the system in order to get the agent to recognize maven

Comment: Add a screenshot from agent pool with the agent capabilities

Comment: i have added MAVEN_HOME and  in environment variables

Comment: You have to restart the agent after you add environment variables. And the error message is telling you that the agent version is too low.

Comment: The agent version which ive downloaded is "2.146.0"